# Redirection through Regular expression oscthumb.php query string unable

Tags: regex, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am unable to solve this one. I need to redirect this kind of urls:

```
http://www.example.com/oscthumb.php?src=/images/image.jpg
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/oscthumb.php?src=/images/image.jpg&w=150&h=131.8125&f=jpg&q=95&hash=317ec2edb3fa82e56787a5f3308d5e96
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg
```

without parameters. Image.jpg can vary

How can I do that in `.htaccess`?

I tried this but it doesn't work properly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/oscthumb\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^src=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Remembering that SO is not a code-writing service, what have you tried so far and why didn't it help?

Comment: So far this is the best I managed to get:
[code]RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/oscthumb\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^src=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1 [R=301,L][/code]

Comment: In the end what I only need is to capture the name and extension of the image file so I can output http://www.example.com/images/Filename.Extension

Comment: @MandyShaw can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I was only the person who checked the question to make sure there was enough information for the community to pick it up - I'm not a subject matter expert I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
$url = $_GET['src'];
header('Location: http://www.example.com/' . $url);
exit;
```

**EDIT:**
.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.jpg
RewriteRule =([^=]+\.jpg) http://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I want to do it through .htaccess, is that possible?

Comment: It possible, but you posted tag 'php')))

Comment: Sorry, my fault is the first question. Do you know how is would be in htaccess?

Comment: @andrewbaltimore Do you have every time `images/image.jpg` code in that urls, or it can be diferrent images?

Comment: image.jpg changes to different names that can have letters, numbers and dashes

Comment: It is not working in this simulator https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, can you check?